# How to customize 502 page in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js, webfaction

When I try to access my URL running a Node.js app, when the app not running, the page shows

> 502 – Bad Gateway
>
> The page you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again
>   later.
>
> If you are the website owner, please see Error: 502 Bad Gateway
>   documentation for more   information and possible steps to resolve the
>   problem.

It's hosted on webfaction.

Is there a way to customize what shows on this page?

Comment: That comes from your host's proxy.  Ask them.

Answer (score -1):

This error isn't caused by node.js; it is caused by a proxy between you and node.js. This may mean that your server isn't running. Try contacting webfaction.